# Lots of data in one column vs lots of small rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am interested in the performance of each of the following, specifically in SQL Server.

Simple overall concept: I have objects (let's say `Type1`) that each have a list of another type of object (let's say `Type2`).

My current schema has a table for each type. Table1 holds `Type1` and Table2 holds `Type2`. For each record in Table2 there is a reference linking each `Type2` to its respective `Type1`.

So now for the question. I haven't gone too far into making this yet, so I'm not too far in to change. I don't plan on ever pulling up a `Type2` object individually from the database. I will always pull a `Type1` which will either come with the list of `Type2` objects or have a method to retrieve them. In this case would it be better to just serialize the list of `Type2` objects (say, to JSON) and store them in a column in `Table1` for each `Type1`? Would I notice a slow down if this column were to get very very large?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is: would you ever, under any circumstances, make changes to what `Type2`s are available? Almost certainly the answer is yes: at some point in the future you will want to add one, or remove one, or edit one. And given that, having them serialized in JSON will be disadvantageous.

Keep the arrangement you have with two separate tables, create an `INDEX` on the `Type1` ID in `Table2` (so the query to find the associated `Type2`s will be nice and speedy, even if the table becomes extremely large), and you shouldn't have any trouble.